# In the VirtoCommerce Storefront order paid notification how do we get last four digits ofcredit card from customer_order object?

Tags: virtocommerce

In the VirtoCommerce Storefront the order paid notification has access to customer_order object.  We cannot find any documentation on what fields are available on that object.  We need the last 4 of the credit card as well as time (with time zone) the charge was made as well as the authorization number.

It would also be great if we could have a complete property/field list and description of each of the objects listed as available in each notification.

Answer (score 1):

All order notification data templates inherited from [OrderEmailNotificationBase](https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-module-order/blob/master/VirtoCommerce.OrderModule.Data/Notifications/OrderEmailNotificationBase.cs#L11).

The customer_order object is [VirtoCommerce.Domain.Order.Model.CustomerOrder](https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-module-core/blob/master/VirtoCommerce.Domain/Order/Model/CustomerOrder.cs) type.

Notice that the property should be converted from Camel notation to lowercase and underscores, because of the DotLiquid engine we use in this template and because it uses Ruby notation for all the properties.

So, the complete liquid example of the customer model. Unfortunately, I could not post the complete document here:

```
{
    "customer_id": "string",
    "customer_name": "string",
    "channel_id": "string",
    "store_id": "string",
    "store_name": "string",
    "organization_id": "string",
    "organization_name": "string",
    "employee_id": "string",
    "employee_name": "string",
    "outer_id": "string",
    "shopping_cart_id": "string",
    "is_prototype": true,
    "subscription_number": "string",
    "subscription_id": "string",
    "addresses": [
        {
            "key": "string",
            "address_type": "Billing",
            "name": "string",
...
```

Comment: https://community.virtocommerce.com/t/whats-customer-order-object-in-the-notifications-templates/97

Comment: I don't see any resource that contains the last 4 digits of the credit card used.  Did I miss it ?

Comment: This information should be stored in the payment document and depend on the implementation of the payment method.